# Linux 12.10 quantal does not load NVIDIA driver version 313.18 for GeForce GT 650M

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, xorg

I have an HP Envy DV7 7212 with the GeForce GT 650M. I dual boot Windows 8 and Linux 12.10, Quantal. The video hardware operates properly under Windows 8. The Linux drivers are not loaded by the time that I try to login to X.

I get what looks like a safe X boot screen at 600x800 resolution

I've generated a great number of log files and reference some of their data here

nvidia-installer.log for the 313.18 installer shows no errors and successful completion

I've added blacklist entries in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf for nouveau and nvidiafb and my lsmod does not show them loaded. Though, the nvidia module is loaded with 0 users associated with it.

The system is running :

```
Linux TheTurk 3.7.0-030700-generic #201212102335 SMP Tue Dec 11 04:36:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release produces the following output

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```

Using the nvidia-debugdump tool to list graphics devices I receive the following output

```
Found 1 NVIDIA devices
    Device ID:              0
    Device name:            GeForce GT 650M
    GPU internal ID:        GPU-1641f115-0090-aa40-d0ff-ae73bf5e3f85
```

lsmod provides a number of output items, however, the following are key

```
...
nvidia               9139978  0 
...
uvcvideo               82215  0 
videobuf2_core         36138  1 uvcvideo
videodev              130085  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
...
video                  19413  1 i915
```

> lshw -C display

produces the following output

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GK107 [GeForce GT 650M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:72000000-72ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff memory:50000000-51ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:52000000-5207ffff   
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:45 memory:73000000-733fffff memory:60000000-6fffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

> lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]]'

produces the following

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 650M] [10de:0fd1] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Xorg.0.log shows some errors claiming

```
    ... 
[    24.355] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    24.355] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    24.593] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    26.822] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    26.822]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    26.822]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    26.822] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  313.18  Wed Jan  9 15:34:35 PST 2013
[    26.845] Loading extension GLX
[    26.845] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    26.845] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    27.003] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    27.003]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.003]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    27.060] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  313.18  Wed Jan  9 15:15:26 PST 2013
[    27.060] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    27.076] (++) using VT number 7

[    27.076] (EE) No devices detected.
...
[    28.531] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found) 
...
```

Having discovered that this could be an Optimus issue. I've installed Bumblebee according to their recommendations http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu
However, I've ended up with some further issues. I'm searching for information on these, but I thought I'd go ahead and record them here for posterity.

First off, I get to the lightdm login screen just fine, but when I enter my password, I end up crashing the X server, or lightdm, and getting sent back to the login prompt, the login prompt reloads with that familiar chiming sound and further attempts to login result in the same crash and prompt repeating.

/var/log/upstart/bumblebee.log repeats the following 2 messages :

> ls: cannot access /usr/lib/nvidia*/libGL.so: No such file or directory
>   /proc/self/fd/9 31: exec: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed: not found

the first message is odd because /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so does exist
the second is string because /usr/sbin/bumblebeed exists

/var/log/upstart/lightdm.log repeats this message :

> ** (process:12342): WARNING **: Error reading existing Xauthority: Error opening file: Permission denied Error writing X authority: Error
>   opening file '/home/gary/.Xauthority': Permission denied

/var/log/syslog repeats this message :

> bumblebeed[]: Module 'nvidia-current' is not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For installing the nvidia 313 driver properly.

Do this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go to your additional driver page and select the nvidia 313 driver.
Wait until the driver is installed and reboot.

This ppa also include the nvidia-current package so it can fix your bumblebeed error.

(srr about the dutch language screenshot)
[image]

Comment: That fixed the bumblebee error. 
After adding the repo that you cited above, I was able to add the additional driver through jocket. 
I wasn't able to get into the GUI, and so I used
`jockey-text --list` 
to get a list of all of the appropriate drivers, then I enabled the driver for 313 through :
`jockey-text -e kmod:nvidia_313`

Comment: This worked for me with GTX 860M, annoying that standard ubuntu didn't make drivers available!!

Answer (score 0):

The .XAuthority permission error was repaired by chown'ing the ~/.XAuthority file
between Thomas15v's answer re: restricted drivers, and my own .XAuthority fix, along with the Bumblebee installation, I'm able to login and run optirun in an operational X environment.